# Resource ID through getIdentifier returns 0

Tags: java, android, xml

```
private String isChecked(String id) {
    id = "R.id." + id;
    int ID = getResources().getIdentifier(id, "id", "com.example.android.justjava");
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(ID);
    return String.valueOf(checkBox.isChecked());
}
```

I pass in a value of `check_whipped_cream`(A check box's id in a xml document) into the function above, but when I debug the app, the variable `ID` always becomes equal to 0. What is wrong with it?

NOTE: The `isChecked()` called in the last line method is from the CheckBox class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the big issue is

```
 id = "R.id." + id;
```

you are asking android to look for `R.id.id` into `id` since you are providing already `"id"` as second argument. It should be just `id`. To avoid issues with misspelled words you should rely on the return value of .getPackageName() instead of hard coding it on your own.

Use

get rid of  `id = "R.id." + id;`

```
getResources().getIdentifier(id, "id", getPackageName());
```

Comment: id is a string... If I insert "hello" it will be "R.id."+"hello"

Comment: if you have and "id" declared with identifier "hello" you have to provide only "hello"

Comment: Oh i understood now... We do not need the R.id. part?

Comment: you don't. The second argument takes care of it.

Answer (score 2):

First, to be sure that the package is correct you could use context.getPackageName()

And your id is wrong, don't concatenate R.id to it, that is your mistake ;)

Answer (score 2):

To understand what is what let's take an example.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_welcome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img_logo"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="YOUR SHOPPING COMPANION!"
        android:textColor="@color/toolbar"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_12"/>
```

In above piece of code, if I want to retrieve this element then I will use

`R.id.lbl_welcome`
It's actual value is in `R.java` file, which is somewhat like this

```
public final class R {
    public static final class id {
        public static final int lbl_welcome=0x7f100197;
    }
}
```

In case you have string name of the view which in our case is `lbl_welcome` then we can use the method `getIdentifier`-

```
getResources().getIdentifier("lbl_welcome", "id", getPackageName());
```

The above piece of code will give you value equivalent to `R.id.lbl_welcome`